# print results of while loop on the same line

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I am writing a program that asks for your input, puts the words of the sentence you entered into a list and makes the words in the statement go trough the while loop one by one.

The while loops works as follows:
if the first letter of a word is a Vowel it print the word + hay. 
Ifthe first letter of the word is not a vowel it puts the first letter of the word at the end of the word + ay

the code:

```
VOWELS = ['a','e','i','o','u']

def pig_latin(phrase):
    #We make sure the input is changed in only lower case letters.
    #The words in your sentence are also putted into a list
    lowercase_phrase = phrase.lower()
    word_list = lowercase_phrase.split()
    print word_list

    x = 0

    while x < len(word_list):

        word = word_list[x]
        if word[0] in VOWELS:
            print word + 'hay'

        else:
            print word[1:] + word[0] + 'ay'
        x = x+1

pig_latin(raw_input('Enter the sentence you want to translate to Pig Latin, do not use punctation and numbers please.'))
```

My problem:
If i enter for example: "Hello my name is John" in the_raw input at the end of the code i will get the following output:

```
ellohay
ymay
amenay
ishay
ohnjay
```

But i actually want the following output:

```
ellohay ymay amenay ishay ohnjay
```

If someone could explain me how to achieve this output it would be appriciated

Comment: `print word[1:] + word[0] + 'ay',`

Answer (score 2):

Save the new words in another list, then at the end:

```
print(" ".join(pig_latin_words))
```

Example:

```
VOWELS = {'a','e','i','o','u'}

def pig_latin(phrase):
    #We make sure the input is changed in only lower case letters.
    #The words in your sentence are also putted into a list
    word_list = phrase.lower().split()
    print(word_list)

    pig_latin_words = []

    for word in word_list:
        if word[0] in VOWELS:
            pig_latin_words.append(word + "hay")
        else:
            pig_latin_words.append(word[1:] + word[0] + "ay")

    pig_latin_phrase = " ".join(pig_latin_words)

    print(pig_latin_phrase)

    return pig_latin_phrase
```

Answer (score 0):

Append a comma (,) at the end of your print statements to avoid the newline:

```
while x < len(word_list):

    word = word_list[x]
    if word[0] in VOWELS:
        print word + 'hay',

    else:
        print word[1:] + word[0] + 'ay',
    x = x+1
```